# Reveal Hidden items in Sets of 3

Tags: jquery

I have a parent DIV with children DIVs.

1. The parent div by default lists 12 items (or more) but only shows 6. The rest are rendered but hidden with CSS
2. There's a "Show More" link at the bottom of the parent div. Clicking on it will reveal 3 more DIVs
3. There is no "Show Less" so that is not needed - to go backwards

What I have so far:
All the above functionality working great. Until... I had to add another parent DIV with the same functionality on the page. Now the second parent "Show More" was activating the first DIV. How can I extend this functionality so that the Show More functionality is contained to the parent - this way, I can add multiple DIV's with the same functionality?

Code below:

HTML

```
<div class="lo-profile-cards">
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 1</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 2</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 3</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 4</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 5</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 6</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 7 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 8 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 9 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 10 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time)</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 11 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 12 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
<a href="#" class="show-more-los">Show More</a>
</div>

<!-- SECOND DIV WITH SAME FUNCTIONALITY -->
<div class="lo-profile-cards">
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 1</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 2</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 3</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 4</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 5</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 6</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 7 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 8 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 9 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 10 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time)</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 11 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
<div class="lo-profile-card">Card 12 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
<a href="#" class="show-more-los">Show More</a>
</div>
```

JS

```
// SHOW MORE LOS
    $(function () {
        $('.show-more-los').click(function () {
            $('.lo-profile-cards .lo-profile-card:hidden').slice(0, 3).show();
            if ($('.lo-profile-cards .lo-profile-card').length == $('.lo-profile-cards .lo-profile-card:visible').length) {
                $('.show-more-los ').hide();
            }
        });
    });
```

CSS

```
.lo-profile-cards .lo-profile-card:nth-child(n+7)
    {
        display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.closest()` to get closest outer div from show more and then use `.find()` to access elements inside that outer div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('.show-more-los').click(function() {
    //use .closest and then use find to access only div where show more is clicked
    $(this).closest('.lo-profile-cards').find('.lo-profile-card:hidden').slice(0, 3).show();
    if ($(this).closest('.lo-profile-cards').find('.lo-profile-card').length == $(this).closest('.lo-profile-cards').find('.lo-profile-card:visible').length) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.lo-profile-cards .lo-profile-card:nth-child(n+7) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lo-profile-cards">
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 1</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 2</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 3</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 4</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 5</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 6</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 7 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 8 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 9 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 10 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 11 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 12 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
  <a href="#" class="show-more-los">Show More</a>
</div>

<!-- SECOND DIV WITH SAME FUNCTIONALITY -->
<div class="lo-profile-cards">
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 1</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 2</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 3</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 4</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 5</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 6</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 7 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 8 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 9 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 10 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 11 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 12 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
  <a href="#" class="show-more-los">Show More</a>
</div>
```

Alternative is using `.parent()` instead of `.closest()` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('.show-more-los').click(function() {
   //use parent
    $(this).parent().find('.lo-profile-card:hidden').slice(0, 3).show();
    if ($(this).parent().find('.lo-profile-card').length == $(this).parent().find('.lo-profile-card:visible').length) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.lo-profile-cards .lo-profile-card:nth-child(n+7) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lo-profile-cards">
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 1</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 2</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 3</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 4</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 5</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 6</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 7 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 8 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 9 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 10 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 11 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 12 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
  <a href="#" class="show-more-los">Show More</a>
</div>

<!-- SECOND DIV WITH SAME FUNCTIONALITY -->
<div class="lo-profile-cards">
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 1</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 2</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 3</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 4</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 5</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 6</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 7 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 8 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 9 (hidden, will be revealed with show more)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 10 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time)</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 11 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
  <div class="lo-profile-card">Card 12 (hidden, will be revealed with show more pressed second time</div>
  <a href="#" class="show-more-los">Show More</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @swati thanks for that so quickly. It does not work for me. When I click the "Show More", nothing is revealed. In stead, the words "Show More" disappear. I'm bound to //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js for this. Could that be the problem?

Comment: no working fine with that version as well you can check updated code . I think problem is somewhere else . can you show updated code  or maybe create jsfiddle ?

Comment: or i think [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) might be causing problem you can scroll down that link and see its `deprecated` from 1.7 version . Alternate is to use `.parent()`

Comment: No luck with parent as well. I'll update with a jsfiddle. Thanks!

Comment: I get this in error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).parent() is not a function. I just replaced .closest with .parent from your script

Comment: I have updated my code with `.parent()` check if that works for you.